# WPF - Change label look on mouse over

Tags: wpf, label

I have a WPF label and want to change its look on mouse over or hover. 
This question shows how to do it with TextBlock and not quite what I want [using a trigger to set a textblock foreground on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471771/using-a-trigger-to-set-a-textblock-foreground-on-mouseover).
It's different because with `Label`, changing foreground did not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the example from the question that you linked from, but changing the word `TextBlock` to `Label` works just fine for changing the `Foreground`, so you'll have to provide more information if you really can't get it to work. Try this:

```
<Label Content="My colour changes just fine" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Note that if you set the `Foreground` on the actual `Label` element, as you did in your answer, instead of in the `Style` then *that* would stop the `Trigger` from working, so don't do this:

```
<Label Content="My colour changes just fine" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" /> <!-- This won't work -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" /> <!--This won't work-->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it. Ignore other properties, focus on `Label.Style`.
Using a `Label` allows you to align text as I showed below. That does not work with `TextBlock`.

```
<Label Content="Hover over me" Name="lblSeasons" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkBlue" Width="150" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Height="50" 
       VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Aqua"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```